# Integrate 'Watch on YouTube' link on app

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am building a music app for which i want to have a 'Watch on Youtube' Link. 
Is it possible to have the YT logo that opens directly to the suggested video?

How do I integrate a feature like this?

I am basically building a media app that shows a list of all songs the user can listen to. I wish to include a Youtube icon next to each song entry and give the user the option to watch it on Youtube upon click.

Thanks
Sonia

Comment: I think it is possible as I have seen similar features, but the question does not really indicate what you are asking. First of all what kind of application are you developing and what programming language, frameworks etc are you using. Then you could also post some code which could help people to understand the problem and show the effort of your side to solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, What i meant was -

I am building a media app that shows a list of all songs the user can listen to. I wish to include a Youtube icon next to each song entry and give the user the option to watch it on Youtube upon click.

Answer (score 0):

The question you have asked is not quite correct ,but if you're asking for this - here you go

```html
// Comment:  target="_blank" for people to open another window. <br/>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">
<img src="https://www.youtube.com/yt/about/media/images/brand-resources/icons/YouTube_icon_full-color.svg" width="100px" height="100px" />
</a>
<br/>
   // Comment: change link inside brackets in order to get different image src="https://www.youtube.com/yt/about/media/images/brand-resources/icons/YouTube_icon_full-color.svg"
   // Comment: change the link inside brackets to use custom youtube link ,I have just picked the homepage to make it easy href="https://www.youtube.com/"
```

well it is like this in html ,hopefully you get the point

Comment: Sorry, What i meant was - I am building a media app that shows a list of all songs the user can listen to. I wish to include a Youtube icon next to each song entry and give the user the option to watch it on Youtube upon click.